# Delete all newline characters not followed by ‘£’ on the next line in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a very large file, and I want to remove all newline characters at the end of each line, so to merge all, except if the line starts with the character `£`.

So, if I have this:

```
data1
data2
£data3
data4
data5
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
data1data2
£data3data4data5
```

I was thinking of something like

```
:%s/\n(but not \n£)//g
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution offered by @pb2q will remove all newlines *and a next character* if this character is not a “£” *or a newline* (because collection doesn’t match a newline by default), while in your question you asked to remove only the newline. This can be fixed by either using `\ze`, or a negative look-ahead:

```
%s/\n\ze\_[^£]
%s/\n£\@!
```

Note some things: first, you can omit a replacement string if you want to delete some text (unless you need to have a substitution flags which you don’t in this case). Second, `\_` adds newline to a collection. It can be also written as `[^£\n]`, but I guess it is not the best thing you can do: any guy coming from some PCRE-capable language thinks about `[^£\n]` as “match anything except ‘£’ and newline”, while in Vim it is really “match anything (including newline) except ‘£’”.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove all new lines, then add them again where they should be. Or use a negative look ahead, but this is simpler, easier, and more comprehensible to anyone.

```
s/\n//g
s/£/\n£/g
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the file was too big. Kept crashing all the time.

Comment: That's ridiculous and not an issue with the answer - your editor is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following `:global` command:

```
:g/^[^£]/-j!
```

It goes through all the lines that start with any character but `£`,
going from top to bottom, and joins each of those lines with the
preceding one via the `:join` command.